# How can I build multi-step form in angualrjs?

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I have this below code in my template where I use ng-include to load my form. the form has 1 field where user enters a number. When user submits, I want to load another form that will replace the current one & will display the number of textfields that user entered.
In my controller, I am getting the html for my next form but I the current form is still displayed. I don't know whether this is the right way to do it.

```
<div class="row text-center white">
<div class="col-md-4  col-md-offset-4">
    <h2>Welcome</h2>        
    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'template_1'"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juste have a controller + a template by step.
Each time a step is completed, save the step data in sessionStorage or a non-persistent service and display the next step by goiing to the next controller.

At the end of your steps, you send all your steps data to the server..
Don't forget to clean stored data at the right time to prevent showing forever last typed values.

pretty straight forward

Comment: "display the next step by changing the app route". What exactly do you mean here?

Comment: Well just a basic <a href="/step2">Next step</a> in order go to the next controller (step). Edited post.

Comment: Ok. got it. This works now. but the thing is the route forces to render whole view. If you see my code above then except for ng-include , I want the rest of the code available on all pages. So, I just want to replace the ng-include div with new form.

Comment: "I want the rest of the code available on all pages" can you clarify this ? If you store data, and go to a previous step, you'll be able to retrieve/construct the view as is. Another option is to have all your steps in one view and just ng-show ng-hide the rights steps depending on your requirements

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood. I want only the form to change. That is the reason I used ng-include. The rest of the elements like header and footer should be the same. When route is changed, the whole view changes. In this case, I will have to include header as well as footer in my new route template. I will be fine if there is a solution which does not change route.

Comment: yeah a route change change the view, but it's common in angular. Just having a ng-view tag on a DIV in your HTML tell angular to refresh only this DIV. see @http://jsfiddle.net/terebentina/Wy7Ww/